# Copy date into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to copy data from one sheet to another based on some filters.

The Column I is a date which is based on the formula Column I = Column A + 10 days.
My Macro copies Column In to Column F of new sheet.I want the date to copied in the same format as it is there. For eg if Column A is 4/1/2020 then Column I will be showing 4/11/2020 . I want the Macro to copy the same way and paste 4/11/2020 to the column F.

```
    With sourceSheet

        ' Get last row
         lastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="PENDING"
        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="USA"    ', Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="CANADA"
        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="USA"     ', Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="CANADA"

        .Range("K2:K" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("G2")
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A2")
        .Range("E2:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("B2")
        .Range("G2:G" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("C2")
        .Range("I2:I" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("F2")



    End With
```

Comment: What's happening now? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi @BigBen The Column I has a formula in it....so when the macro copies it...it  shows as #ref....I want the date to be copied

Comment: Then paste values.

Comment: I tried that....it is not working...I tried this......Range("I2:I" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
         targetSheet.Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: It means that it is copying the data but not in date format...In general format...instead of showing 4/11/2020...it is showing 43297

Comment: Then paste the formats afterwards or use `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`.

Comment: Yes it worked...I did the following.....Range("I2:I" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
         targetSheet.Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210758/discussion-between-roy-and-bigben).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below..

```
.Range("I2:I" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
         targetSheet.Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```